# How do I retrieve CloudKit Reference List?

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have setup my CloudKit record types the same as my local structs and models in my code but can't seem to find a way to retrieve the list of references.

For example, I have a `UserData` record type with a record field of `friends` which is a list of references to `Friend` record type.

Local models:

```
struct User {
    let id: UUID
    let friends: [Friend]
    let username: String
}
struct Friend {
    let id: UUID
    let username: String
}
```

And this is the code I use to attempt to retrieve the friends

```
@State var friends = [Friend]()

        if let userID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID") {
            let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: CKRecord.ID(recordName: userID)) { (record, error) in
                if let fetchedInfo = record {
                    friends = (fetchedInfo["friends"] as? [Friend])!
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

So I guess the main question is how do I retrieve a list record field from CloudKit as it does not seem to return the value as an array.

Comment: Could you show us your db structure and a sample record from the debugger? It should come back as an array.

Comment: Go to CloudKit Dashboard see view the record type and see the fields in the record type. See how the relationship is built. If your project uses `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` then core data syncing is taken care of automatically, and in your record type in cloudkit look for CD_<relationship name>. If it is a many to many look for recordType "CDMR". CloudKit dashboard and see all the record types and go through each one. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/202